# Setup kickstart boot for all installation media types (cd and usb-flash)

Tags: linux, installation, kickstart, anaconda

I created own custom CentOS iso. I used mkisofs make it.

This is part of my isolinux.cfg file:

```
label vesa
  menu label Install ^RAIDIX system 
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img xdriver=vesa nomodeset text linux ks=cdrom:/isolinux/ks.cfg
```

If I specify parameter `ks=cdrom:/isolinux/ks.cfg` my iso will boot only from cd or dvd-rom.
If I specify parameter `ks=hd:<device>:/ks.cfg` my iso will boot only from usb-drive.

Can I specify ks parameter to boot from both type of installation media?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that when you say "will only boot from" you mean "will only find my kickstart from". In which case no I don't believe you can specify more than one possible location for the kickstart file (though failing to find the kickstart anaconda should ask you for a new location so you should be able to manually enter the correct location).

What you could do, however, is create a second boot label and use a different ks value in that label and you pick the right label based on where your boot media lives.